# Express one constant as a linear combination of two other constants?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let a,b,n,m,o be nonzero rational scalars.

How do I express o as a linear combination of n and m with coefficients a and b?

Explicitly how to find a,b such that an + bm = o?

I know how to do linear interpolation for the y=f(x) case but am stumped looking at this one although I think it is very similar.

Through guesswork I found a solution to be a = (m-o)/(m-n) and b=(o-n)/(m-n) but I'd like a more systematic way of obtaining it.

Edit:
From my solution it seems like a+b = 1 but I'm not sure why this happens/if it is significant or a coincidence. Perhaps because the coefficient of o is 1?

Comment: Are you familiar with Bezout's Identity or the extended Euclidean algorithm? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bézout%27s_identity)  It gives a (systematic) way to solve this problem in general as long as $o$ is a multiple of $\gcd(m,n)$ (if it isn't then the problem doesn't have a solution anyway)

Comment: I'm actually looking for the case where a,b are fractions and from the solution I found it appears that a+b = 1 but I'm not sure if that is significant.